# ¿Cómo mandar una aplicación Android a segundo plano?

Tags: java, android

Estoy empezando a trabajar con Android Studio y me están surgiendo dudas.

Mi problema es el siguiente:

> Tengo una aplicación que tiene una "Splashscreen" o pantalla de
>   presentación y funciona como lanzador de esta. Tras unos segundos
>   salta a otra actividad para realizar el login.

Cuando se presenta esta segunda pantalla (login) me gustaría que al pulsar el botón de atrás,

```
 @Override public void onBackPressed() {}
```

y por medio de esta acción mandar la aplicación al segundo plano.

Es el mismo comportamiento que presenta la gran mayoría de las aplicaciones por lo que supongo que existirá algún método para resolverlo fácilmente.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La mayoria de las aplicaciones realizan la terminación de la Activity mediante `finish()`, y tu ves un shortcut para acceder nuevamente.

En el caso que comentas puedes usar

```
moveTaskToBack(true);
```

Que mueve la tarea conteniendo esta Activity al fondo  del stack de Activities.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

Comment: ¡Gracias! Funciona perfectamente